# Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Tags: visual-basic

Здравствуйте. В программе Visual Basic выскакивает ошибка

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

на строке

```
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Books\" + Pictures(k)).
```

Что мне делать?

Comment: проверять размер массива/последовательности и значение индекса. И поменяйте пожалуйста заголовок вопроса - он не соответствует содержанию

Answer (score 1):

> Что мне делать?

Ответ из комментария:

Проверять размер массива/последовательности и значение индекса.

Answer (score 1):

Да, дело скорее всего в значении переменной **k**.

И ещё не мешало-бы заменить знак **+** на **&**, тоже может быть причиной, однако обычно такое вызывает не 9-й код.

А в начале каждой формы/модуля в НЕ релизной версии добавлять

```
option explicit
```

Это поможет дебажить код.